# Download executable with curl

Tags: curl, argocd

I am following the documentation to install Argo CD, and I need to install a package for Linux present here: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases
If I do it through the Explorer I have no problem to install it but using `curl` I get the following error (both as root and as normal user):

```
curl -sSL https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/v2.0.1/argocd-util-linux-amd64 -o .
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1369)
```

The verbose mode does not give me much information

Answer (score 0):

i think this happens as github downloads/redirects from githubusercontent idk
Try this

```
curl -LJO https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/v2.0.1/argocd-util-linux-amd64

-L --location
-J --remote-header-name
-O --remote-name
```

if you try `wget`

```
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.121.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/120896210/9da49480-9e3b- 
11eb-9e9b-706ed4210355?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz- 
Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210423%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X- 
Amz-Date=20210423T145336Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz- 
Signature=dc9310ece835c05901c4a051735560c9445c7ba34008e5404516f609c5d490a9&X- 
Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=120896210&response-content- 
disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dargocd-util-linux-amd64&response-content- 
type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2021-04-23 16:53:36--  https://github- 
releases.githubusercontent.com/120896210/9da49480-9e3b-11eb-9e9b-706ed4210355?X- 
Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz- 
Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210423%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X- 
Amz-Date=20210423T145336Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz- 
Signature=dc9310ece835c05901c4a051735560c9445c7ba34008e5404516f609c5d490a9&X- 
Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=120896210&response-content- 
disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dargocd-util-linux-amd64&response-content- 
type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving github-releases.githubusercontent.com (github- 
releases.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.109.154, 185.199.110.154, 
185.199.108.154, ...
Connecting to github-releases.githubusercontent.com (github- 
releases.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.109.154|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 89473879 (85M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘argocd-util-linux-amd64’
```

it follows the link to the final one i guess.

ref : https://gist.github.com/jwebcat/5122366

Comment: With wget I can install it ans save it in `/usr/local/bin/argocd` but it does not detect it when I call it, even though it is in the `PATH`

Comment: i don't get it.. i tried it and it works fine, if not try downloading it and putting in the path, and make sure to ```chmod +x argocd```